# Submit an XML form via AJAX using Joomla.submitbutton/form

Tags: joomla-3.x, ajax, form

I know there are a few questions regarding how to submit forms with AJAX but i could not figure out how to do it in my case.

Should it be something like this?

```
 $("#adminForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    Joomla.submitform(''document.getElementById('adminForm'));
  });
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'index.php?option=com_gallery&format=ajax&view=gallery&task=submit&tmpl=component'
   data: {
       form: jQuery(form).serializeArray()
   },
   success: function(response){
    var res= jQuery.parseJSON(res);

    if ( res.Res == 1 ) {                       
      console.log("ok");
    }
    else {               

        console.log("error");         
    }               
   }    
   dataType: 'html'
 });
});
```

My form:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm" class="form-validate">
       <fieldset name="details">
         <legend>Details</legend>
         <?php echo $this->form->renderFieldset('details');  ?>
       </fieldset>       
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('send.submit')">Send</button> 

    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
</form>
```

My question is:

How can i submit form via AJAX using the `Joomla.submitbutton()` function (or any other function such as `Joomla.submitform()`)
  and what is the best practice for it?

Probably i have to remove `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('send.submit')">Send</button>` but changes have to be made in the AJAX call.
i don't know how to do it as my form uses `Joomla.submitbutton()`.

Would i have to add the form id and also the `Joomla.submitbutton` or `Joomla.submitform` function to the AJAX call?

Should i add the controller name to the url too in the AJAX call?

`index.php?option=com_gallery&format=ajax&view=gallery&task=send.submit&tmpl=component`

Comment: Joomla Ajax documentation at https://docs.joomla.org/API_Guides and worked example at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_AJAX. Usually you'd trigger an ajax call from a form field being changed, or something like that. A submit button would be used to trigger a normal HTTP POST.

Comment: Yes but like i want to submit my form data via AJAX to my controller `send.php` specifically to the function `submit()` whrn the submit button is clicked. But then i would have to, somehow, call the `Joomla.submitbutton` function in the AJAX or something. It's like a normal AJAX post but i don't know how to do it with Joomla.

Comment: OK, in that case don't use the Joomla submitbutton functionality, because this will submit the form in a normal HTTP POST. Just have a normal javascript onclick listener on your submit button which fires your javascript code, which then makes the ajax call. Using the JResponseJson class in your server php code handling the ajax request makes things easy, eg allows you to easily send back enqueueMessage messages to appear in the Message area in the form.

Comment: Oh thank you very much. That's what i was looking for!

Comment: If I want to use another approach other than one given in the docs, how should i call the method in the controller `send.php`? Should i add the controller name to the url in the AJAX call? `index.php?option=com_gallery&task=send.submit` or just `index.php?option=com_gallery&task=submit` because i have seen examples with both and it confuses me.

Comment: I just figured it out. We need to add the controller name to the url. I have also tried `index.php?option=com_gallery&controller=send&task=submit` but the only one who has worked out for me was `index.php?option=com_gallery&task=send.submit`

Comment: It's the code in your main gallery.php file which processes the task parameter, and by convention in Joomla pretty much always does the same thing. Have a look at https://docs.joomla.org/Model-View-Controller#The_HTTP_Request_task_parameter. This is true for all types of HTTP requests - GET / POST and Ajax / non-Ajax

Comment: Oh, i see, so the main file processes the task parameter. Yes i got it working however i ended up asking another question because now i need to get a specifc value but i don't know how to do it in a proper way.